# Sample size calculations (based on proportions) with a 3x2 factorial design

Tags: sample-size

I'm trying to calculate the sample sizes for a three arm RCT (1:1:1). After allocation to each arm, patients will get further randomised (1:1) for a second intervention.

See the below Table. I've assumed the intervention (row "1") would increase % of patients with the outcome by 20%. Also that Arm 1 and Arm 3 would be equivalent, and that the proportion of patients in Arm 2 with the outcome would be 10% less than in other arms.

[image]

Can anyone advise on the appropriate approach (and ideally suggest software and the appropriate commands) to make this work?